# Char* copying to another char* runtime error

Tags: c++, pointers, char, copy

When I try to run the folling code it's stops working and I don't get it why.

If I could get some help I would appreciate that.

```
const char *p="people";
char *q="random";
 while(*p)
{
    *q=*p;
    *p++;
    *q++;
}
```

Comment: You need to turn up the warnings on you compiler.  `char *q="random";` should be at least a warning and really should be an error.

Comment: `char *q="random";` points to another `const char*` and writing there is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the line

```
char *q="random";
```

is not correct in C++. If you turn on the warning level of the compiler, you should get some warning. By using `-Wall` with `g++`, I get the following warning:

> ```
> warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
>     char *q="random";
> ```

It is not OK to modify the contents of what `q` points. Modifying the contents of what `q` points to is cause for undefined behavior.

What you need to do is create an array of `char` and modify the contents of the array.

```
char q[] = "random";
```

This allows you to modify the contents of `q`. However, if you define `q` to be an array, you can't use `++q` or `q++`. You will need to use another variable to iterate over the array.

Secondly, dereferencing the pointers the lines below seems to indicate to me that you are not sure what's happening.

```
*p++;
*q++;
```

Due to operator precedence, they are equivalent to:

```
*(p++);
*(q++);
```

The pointers are incremented, then they are dereferenced but the dereferenced values are not used. Once again, by turning the warning levels up, you can catch such issues. I get the following warnings with `g++ -Wall`.

> ```
>  warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
>    *p++;
>
>  warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
>    *q++;
> ```

You can just increment the pointers and not try to dereference them.

Here's an updated version of your program that works for me.

```
int main()
{
   const char *p="people";
   char q[] = "random";
   char *cp = q;
   while(*p)
   {
      *cp = *p;
      p++;
      cp++;
   }
}
```

**Caveat**

The definition of the variable `q` is fragile in the above program. It works by coincidence that the length of the string `"people"` is equal to the length of the string `"random"`. If you were to change `p` to.

```
const char *p="a large number of people";
```

the program will break since `q` does not have enough space to hold such a large string.

To be safe, you'll have to use dynamic memory allocation.

```
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
   const char *p="a large number fo people";
   char* q = new char[std::strlen(p)+1];
   char *cp = q;
   while(*p)
   {
      *cp = *p;
      p++;
      cp++;
   }
   *cp = '\0';

   // Use q
   // ...
   //

   // Release dynamically allocated memory.
   delete [] q;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time i really appreciate your help ! :)

Comment: @PatrikTóth, you are welcome. Please not that I fixed an error. The line `*cp = '\n';` needed to be `*cp = '\0';`.

Answer (score 1):

when assigning a `char *` to a string literal (`char *q="random";`), the pointer is directed to "read-only" data, thus any operation trying to modify (`*q = ...`) it will not work as expected as it undefined behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Your code is **not** copying a `char*` to a `char*`; it's copying an **array** of `char` to an **array** of `char`. And the array that it's copying to is not modifiable.

Answer (score 0):

Both, "people" and "random" are strings usually allocated in the read-only memory. Your program tries to write over the read-only 'random' string. Depending on the compiler and operating system the behavior will be different.

Do not do it!

You'd be better if you use an array for 'random':

```
char random[] = {"random"};
char *q = random;
```

or malloc

```
char *q = (char*)malloc(7);
strcpy(q, "random");
```

Comment: `{"random"}` -> `"random"`

Comment: What is the magic  number `7` you pass as parameter to `malloc`?

Comment: size of the string needed to contain 'random' ( 6 + 1 for '0').